# Using workflow to set choice field value

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, designer-workflow, choice-field

I created a workflow which would change the dropdown value when the people picker field had a name, then it would send out an email. However, when i edit an item and select a name and save, the workflow is triggered but does not actually do what it's suppose to. It remains stuck in "Workflows in Progress". I'm thinking there may be something wrong with my logic?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU51A.png) is the workflow I came up with.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is actually your Email step that is not working correctly. The recipient does not look right.

What I normally do to find out where my workflow gets stuck is I insert steps that adds entry to the Workflow History. There is a step to log a workflow history.

If you are emailing the person specified in the People Picker, use the Email Address or Display Name. If your People Picker allows multiple values, use the formatting with proper delimiters (e.g., semicolon).

Comment: I have other workflows sending out emails with no problem. I don't know why it shows users like this but it's the correct format. I've noticed that anything that involves changing the currentItem (I haven't tried changing another item) causes the error. I ended up using Javascript to change the item status instead of the workflow.

Comment: So has this workflows sent an email at all?

Comment: Yes, emails send no problem. It's anything that tries to change the current item that causes an error

Comment: So the emails are sent through the same step you posted here? Does your People Picker allow multiple entries? You might try what I suggested and log a workflow history until you find which step is not working.

Answer (score 1):

That 2. In-Progress doesn't look right to me. When you set that up, did it present you with available options since it's a choice field or did you add that in yourself?

Comment: It presented me with available choices. I added the numbers 1-4 before the choices to keep them in order.